# support to different WebSphere through maven pom

Tags: maven, websphere, pom.xml

i want to change my maven pom.xml so that my pom.xml can be support for different WebSphere's during WebSphere up-gradation. 
Means i want to change my pom.xml, so that it could support both the WS7 and WS8. So can anyone suggest what are the approach needed to make the pom support both WS , so that WebSphere up-gradation will not make any affect in during maven Build.

Comment: What do you mean by support? deploying to WebSphere ? or dependencies for different versions of websphere

Comment: Deploying to websphere

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven build profiles to build for [different environments](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html).

Comment: what will be the parameters for this thing?

Comment: mvn -P profile1 install , "profile1" is the id of the profile

Comment: Not this one, I want  to know what will be the properties in the profile for a websphere deployment.